# Plot[Im[f[x]],...] incorrectly gives graph of identical zero function

Tags: plotting, functions, bugs, complex

**This bug has been fixed in `V11.2.0` or earlier. Regression in `V12.1.0`.**

---

Consider

```
Plot[Im[(1 + (-1)^(2/3)*x)/((-1)^(2/3) + x)], {x, 0, 1}]
```

At least in Mma 11 it gives the following picture:[image: zero]

Meanwhile,

```
Plot[Im[ComplexExpand[(1 + (-1)^(2/3)*x)/((-1)^(2/3) + x)]], {x, 0, 
  1}]
```

gives

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: My initial guess is that it's a bug, and `Plot` is doing some transformation that it shouldn't.

Comment: At the same time, e.g., `Plot[Im[1/((-1)^(2/3) + x)], {x, 0, 1}]` works as expected.

Comment: It works with arbitrary precision: `Plot[Im[(1 + (-1)^(2/3)*x)/((-1)^(2/3) + x)], {x, 0, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 10]`. It works with a black-box machine-precision function: `f[x_?NumericQ] := Im[(1 + (-1)^(2/3)*x)/((-1)^(2/3) + x)];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]`.  And a third way: `Plot[Im[(1 + (-1.)^(2/3)*x)/((-1)^(2/3) + x)], {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, the erroneous behavior is very fragile. Can it be related to (-1)^(...) representation of complex numbers? I myself make mistakes from time to time when checking for presence of complex numbers with `_Complex` pattern. Maybe Mma erroneously assumes the argument of `Im` is real as there are no `Complex` heads? But then why `Plot[Im[1/((-1)^(2/3) + x)], {x, 0, 1}]` work fine?

Comment: Sorry for all the experiments. NOPE: `Plot[N@Im[(1 + (-1)^(2/3)*x)/((-1)^(2/3) + x)], {x, 0, 1}]`. Add `Evaluate`, and YEP: `Plot[Evaluate@N@Im[(1 + (-1)^(2/3)*x)/((-1)^(2/3) + x)], {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: I don't know what it's doing. It seems to fail on a very specific form. Like I said at first, I think it's a bug. I'd report it to WRI.

Comment: `ReImPlot[(1 + (-1)^(2/3)*x)/((-1)^(2/3) + x), {x, 0, 1}]` fails, too, but just on the imaginary part.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ok, I have reported a bug to WRI. Thanks for experimenting.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - but `f[x_] = (1 + (-1)^(2/3)*x)/((-1)^(2/3) + x); ReImPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]` works with v12.2 on my Mac

Comment: @BobHanlon Ah, so the `?NumericQ` protection wasn't really needed (first comment, second example). -- This might be my favorite fix so far, because it seems the most ridiculous: `Plot[Im[(1 + (-1)^(2/3)*x)/((-1)^(2/3) + x) // Evaluate], {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Please update your question if WRI gives you a response.

Comment: @J.M. It is accepted as a bug with status 'In progress' as of now. What should be an update?

Comment: Ah, then I've added the [tag:bugs] tag. If I wasn't available, what you could have done is to edit your question to add a sentence like "WRI Support has confirmed this is a bug."

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it was fixed in `V11.2.0` or earlier. It was fine until `V12.0.0` or later. And there's a regression in `V13.0.0` or earlier.

**`V11.2.0`**

> [image: v11]

**`V12.0.0`**

> [image: v12]

**`V13.0.0`**

> [image: 13]

Answer (score 0):

add a record for v12.1

```
Column[{$Version, Plot[Im[(1 + (-1) ^ (2 / 3) * x) / ((-1) ^ (2 / 3) 
    + x)], {x, 0, 1}], Plot[Im[ComplexExpand[(1 + (-1) ^ (2 / 3) * x) / (
    (-1) ^ (2 / 3) + x)]], {x, 0, 1}]}]
```

[image]